# Ableton's Push / Launchpad color choice

Tags: ableton-live

I'm using the [Launchpad95](http://motscousus.com/stuff/2011-07_Novation_Launchpad_Ableton_Live_Scripts/) script for Novation's Launchpad. I highly recommend it. But i'm curious about one thing.

In the 'Combined Mode' section. Look at the diagram. the bottom left area is a 4x4 grid of colors. These are used to represent the Drum Rack notes.

But why are they color different?

Possibly just to give the user some differentiation?